# Google Drawing API

Tags: api, google-api, drawing

I'm looking for a way to create [Google Drawings](https://docs.google.com/drawings) via API: create/draw shapes/export etc. Is there a Google API for this?

All I find are references to Google Maps drawing and [a forum post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/google-documents-list-api/5IcCEE3M6QU) which talks about the Drive API. Besides that, I can't find anything about the Drawing app.

Does anybody have any idea?

Comment: Can you give us a concrete example?  What do you want to draw?  And why on Google Maps? does the drawing have a fixed number of pixels, or a fixed size in kilometers, so it grows or shrinks when the client zooms?

Comment: drawing a simplified website sitemap with shapes and text via an api. and no im not talking about maps! im talking about https://docs.google.com/drawings API

Comment: Oops, sorry; I must have come here by mistake, between other Google Maps questions.  Sorry

Answer (score 11):

2015: There's currently no such API.

There's this [blog post](http://googleappsdeveloper.blogspot.cz/2010/10/google-drawings-support-added-to.html), which contains obsolete links.
And this [gdata-issues issue](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=API%20ID%20Type%20Status%20Priority%20Stars%20Summary&groupby=&sort=&id=2312) which lies there unnoticed.

**Edit 2022:** Since I wrote the above, Google has removed Google Draw from Drive tools palette. It is still accessible in Google Docs as a thing to insert. But it is obviously an abandoned project/feature - hard to work with, not supported on Android.

Comment: I'm waiting for Google to come out with an app that competes with `graphviz` or `visio`, then they can put out a API. Google draw is probably one of their least used products, doubt they will build an API for it before making the product more useful first.

Comment: Yes, Google Draw is only used in their hiring for design interviews, and it is as painful as it sounds.
I suggest to have a look at http://www.Miro.com instead, which is really well done, performant even on Android, and they are progressing with the API.