# Is it possible to programmatically generate shapes in Drawings with dimensional values from Google Sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

So if I want a rectangle drawn programmatically in Google Drawings for example,  where I have a cell for both the height and width dimensions for this rectangle within a Google Sheet, how could one go about learning how to do this or even find out if this is possible?

Comment: Review documentation for Google Apps Script, and also their REST APIs. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086669/google-drawing-api

Comment: If you really want to use Google Drawings, you can attempt to engineer how the data is stored as bytes, then use a language of your choice to prepare the raw data and use the Drive API to create a file of the given type from raw bytes. This would obviously not be very robust, as any changes to the internal data representation would break your compatibility.